# Directly open issue tab in github repository because this repo is just for issues

Tags: github

I want to open the issues tab when I open repository because I made a repository just for collecting the tasks for all my project , How can we do that ?

Answer (score 2):

As @VonC has said, this is **NOT** configurable. It seems that what you require is an **issue tracker** and not specifically a **repository**. This articles may help you find an issue tracker that fits your purpose:

- http://mashable.com/2014/02/16/bug-tracking-apps/
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system/

Github's feature for referencing issues in commits automatically just by using the `#` and referencing commits in issues using the commit hash id is powerful. But is it a **maintainable** or **scalable** approach to handle issues from different repositories in one central repository? I do **not** think so. Issues are important in project development and should be kept organised the same way we keep code clean and organised.

However, this does **not** mean that it is not possible to maintain your issues in a single github repository. Instead of trying to have the issues tab open automatically, you may create a manual, as a README, for instructions on utilizing the reported issues. This manual will be shown to users visiting the repo. See https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues as an example. You may find this [github article](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/) useful in referencing issues.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be configurable.

That means you need to open your repo directly at the "Issues" page:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/issues
```

Comment: but i can not post an issue even if i follow your method for `https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper`

Comment: @SIslam As an alternative, you can open an issue directly from command-line, using [`gh issue create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_create).